# dill: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable when dill.load() is run from different files

Tags: python, pickle, dill

I use `dill` to store python objects to a file like:

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as output_:
    dill.dump(obj, output_)
```

and than I load stored objects from `test.dprj` file
**C:...\DyS_project\testsread_write.py**

```
import pprint
from MBD_system import read_and_write
from MBD_system.MBD_system import MBDsystem

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MBD_file_abs_path = "C:\...\\test.dprj"
    mbd = read.read(MBD_file_abs_path)
    pprint(vars(mbd))
```

it works fine and object properties are printed. But if I try to load file within application `DySMainWindow` in **C:...\DyS_project\dys.py**

```
from MBD_system.MBD_system import MBDsystem
from MBD_system import read_and_write

class DySMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DySMainWindow, self).__init__()

    def showOpenFileDialog(self):
        ...
        self.MBD_system = None
        self.MBD_system = read_and_write.read(filename)
        print self.MBD_system.__dict__
        pprint(vars(self.MBD_system))
```

dictionary is printed correctly, but when I use `pprint(vars())` to print object's properties it raises:

```
File "C:/.../DyS_project/dys.py", line 577, in showOpenFileDialog
pprint(vars(self.MBD_system))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Any ideas what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: I don't see where you are using `pickle.load` in your code.  Am I missing something?  `dill.dump` is commented out, so if you indeed are using `pickle` and not `dill`, you need to make sure you are using the corresponding module's `load`.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns the problem has been solved. `dill` works OK, the problem was with import of `pprint` package. In the code it was `import pprint` but the correct is `from pprint improt pprint`

Comment: you should answer your own question then, and possibly update the title. Thanks for the follow-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem that was actually a bad hidden type. I have changed the code:

```
import pprint
```

to:

```
from pprint import pprint
```